# How to show servlet run time in IE debug console?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have JSP code as below, I can check run time for javascript code, but I can't check run time for servlet process, runTime is always 0, what can I do?

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    MyForm myForm = (MyForm) request.getAttribute(ACTION_FORM_KEY);
    if(myForm == null) {
        myForm = new PsiSearchForm();
    }

    List<Object> myList = myForm.getMyList();
    if(myList == null) {
        myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long runTime = endTime - startTime;
%>
<html>
    ...
</form>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    console.time('my_form.jsp');
    // javascript process
    console.timeEnd('my_form.jsp');
    console.log("Select My List time: " + <%=runTime%>);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is just not zero because the runtime is under 1 millisecond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `System.nanoTime();`

From [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

```
   long startTime = System.nanoTime();
   // ... the code being measured ...
   long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```